# Unable to Upload Files On Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to upload files on Java Servlet but when i run my **upload.jsp** and select the files to be uploaded and when i hit *submit* it shows me **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**

> upload.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>
        <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" multiple/>
                <input type="submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> FileUpload.java

```
package com.servlet;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*;

@WebServlet("/FileUpload")
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            ServletFileUpload sf = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
            List<FileItem> multifiles = sf.parseRequest(request);
            for(FileItem item : multifiles) {
                item.write(new File("C:/TurboC++/Disk/TurboC3/BIN/Java/Eclipse/Upload-Servlet/" +item.getName()));
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

**> Sorry for posting whole code but i am unable to solve it.**

Comment: `"upload" != "FileUpload"`

Comment: @Gyro Gearless sir what this mean "upload" != "FileUpload". .

Comment: He meant the following: You post it to `/upload` but the servlet is registered to `FileUpload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html form element's `action` attribute's value is the URL to the servlet that will receive the http request from submitting your form. Your `action` attribute is set to `upload`. It appears that you really want it set to `/FileUpload`.

Note that setting it to JUST "/FileUpload" may not be sufficient, but you should give it a try. You may need to either specify the whole URL (e.g. `http://server.com/context/FileUpload`), or a URL relative to the jsp page (eg `/FileUpload`).